# How to run <script> code in a block

Tags: blocks

I'm trying to utilize some pre-built code to display data in a Block. Specifically, show a crude oil price quote in a block.

On oil-price.net, they give you code to embed on an HTML site to display a price quote. So how the heck do i get this on a Block?...it looks like this:

[image]

This is what they give to embed...

`<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://www.oil-price.net/widgets/brent_crude_price_large/gen.php?lang=en">
</script>
<noscript> To get the BRENT <a href="http://www.oil-price.net/dashboard.php?lang=en#brent_crude_price_large">oil price</a>, please enable Javascript.
</noscript>`

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a block (navigate to **Structure** -> **Blocks** -> **Add block** or **http://example.com/admin/structure/block/add**)
2. Make sure you set the **Text format** of the block to "Full Html"
3. Paste in your embed code

Please be aware of the security risks involved http://example.com/admin/help/filter, https://drupal.org/node/213156

Comment: +1 for the security risks. @Dubya - it means "don't do it, unless you really have to".

Comment: @undersound - thx. Yes i had tried that, but the wysiwyg editor strips all the <script> tag info out. Yes have it set to Full HTML.

Comment: Ok, found the solution, in CKEditor settings:
Go to the "Advanced Options" section of your CKEditor profile and add the following string into the text area: config.allowedContent = true;

Comment: How about for drupal 8?

Comment: Is this a Good Practice ?